# Correct way to save and restore a string at various Lifecycle points to an EditText using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I didn't find a good definitive answer to this anywhere (maybe I'm bad at searching?)

The android [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#activity-lifecycle) has various events that will cause a user to lose EditText contents unless you save and restore it during the lifecycle events - typically, using Shared Preferences. Sounds simple, but I can't get it working in practice; despite logging the EditText contents at each event it's not updating on my device when I navigate to another app and then back again.

I have the user type a serial number in an EditText field. Here's what I'm doing in my activity:

```
private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // (boilerplate databinding code omitted here)
    sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}

private fun loadSN() {
    if(sharedPref.contains(PREFERENCE_SN)) {
        binding.serialNumberEditText.setText(sharedPref.getString(PREFERENCE_SN, ""))
        Log.d(TAG, "serialNumberEditText is now ${binding.serialNumberEditText.text.toString()}")
    }
}

private fun saveSN() {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveSN: saving ${binding.serialNumberEditText.text.toString()}")
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString(PREFERENCE_SN, binding.serialNumberEditText.text.toString())
        apply()
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    loadSN()
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    saveSN()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    saveSN()
}
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    loadSN()
}
override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()
    loadSN()
}
```

Sample log output when navigating to a different app then back again:

```
[navigate away from app]
D/FooActivity: saveSN: saving ABCDE
[^^ return to app here]
D/FooActivity: serialNumberEditText is now ABCDE
D/FooActivity: savePreference was called, restoring ABCDE
D/FooActivity: serialNumberEditText is now ABCDE
D/FooActivity: savePreference was called, restoring ABCDE
D/FooActivity: serialNumberEditText is now ABCDE
D/FooActivity: savePreference was called, restoring ABCDE
```

Yet it not restoring ABCDE to the EditText field. Why?

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the data binding code you have omitted above. By the way, your overloads of `onStart`, `onStop`, and `onRestart` are all redundant since `onPause` and `onResume` are always called when the activity loses/gains focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework will save the state of `View`s (including `EditText`s) in the current layout for you automatically, but only while the app is in the "background". That includes when the app is destroyed by the system to reclaim memory, the views will be restored as they were - but not if the user swipes the app away to explicitly close it, or if you remove the layout by e.g. moving to a different `Activity`. If you want the same data to be displayed next time the user opens that layout, you'll need to persist the state yourself, and that does mean something like using `SharedPreferences`.

From your logs it looks like the restoration is happening fine? You're saving `ABCDE`, you set it to `ABCDE` next time you come back, then you check the contents of the `EditText` and it's set to `ABCDE`? What are you seeing instead, and is there anything else that sets data on that view, like data binding in the XML? The system restores the view state before `onStart`, so your restoration happens after that, but if there is any saved state it should be the same data as what you persisted anyway.

Comment: Right, that's the weird thing; clearly despite what the logs say I'm not doing it correctly as `ABCDE` is not restored to the `EditText` on the screen. I'm using databinding to simplify referring to the `TextView` elements that display database metadata. There's a `TextChangedListener` on the `EditText`, but disabling it doesn't affect the behavior.

Comment: You could try adding a breakpoint on the EditText's ``setText`` method (as in, in the ``EditText`` class, ctrl+click the method name to get there) and then debug the app - hopefully it'll stop each time something changes the contents, and you can look at the call stack on the left to see what's setting the wrong thing. Your code seems to be executing fine so it must be something else coming along later and changing it again?

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that UI state is *not* automatically kept when the app is backgrounded or destroyed to reclaim memory: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#ui-dismissal-system

Comment: It is for ``View``s: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#instance-state *"By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save information about each View object in your activity layout (such as the text value entered into an EditText widget). So, if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is restored to its previous state with no code required by you."* You can try it with ``Don't keep activities`` enabled and an ``EditText`` in a layout. Android documentation is wild, I've seen Holo screenshots still around

Comment: @cactustictacs Running the debugger is weird. It works with the debugger breakpoint which calls loadSN 3 times (onRestart, onStart, onResume), yet when I turn the debugger off it doesn't work anymore. It works consistently when I use `Handler` to apply a delay to the call to `setText` inside `loadSN`. Obviously there's some sort of weird race condition going on that's particular to my code, so I'll accept your answer as the generally correct way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewModel and save state module that will do that for you.
Add this to gradle (app level):

```
 dependencies {
        // Java language implementation
        implementation "androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0"
    
        // Kotlin
        implementation "androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.1.0-rc01"
    }
```

if you don't want to use module you can save state via:

```
     @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString("edit_text", yourEditTextView.getText().toString());
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
```

and to retrieve this value

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("edit_text")){
                String valueForEditText = savedInstanceState.getString("edit_text");
                yourEditTextView.setText(valueForEditText);
            }
        }
```

You are not suppose to save state in on stop and on pause, just define your edit text in on create and android will do that for you.

Comment: If you had a really complex UI then I can appreciate why this would  be of interest. However, I feel like it shouldn't require a separate ViewModel to maintain the contents of a single EditText if the user navigates away and back again. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: The simple solution would be to @Override onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState inside your activity. It is enough to handle onPause and onStop calls of your activity. OnDestroy call can be maintained this way only if it caused by screen rotation. You should use shared preferences only if you want to restore EditText state after app was closed by user

Comment: Actually, as I remember it is enough to define your edittext as variable inside your activity class and text inside it will be restored automatically after onPause, onStop calls by Android system. But I can't check it right now.